# Check if Category already exist within database in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, bind

I want to use a bind to another cfm page to check if the database.

The top portion is a query I wrote that i think would work. If the count of Tag is Greater than 0 then the if statement should trigger stating that the Tag has been taken.
I can write the query, but I do not know how to implement it into the logic below it.

**This is my bind page:**

```
<cfquery name="TagCheck" datasource="PostBlog">
select    Count(Category)
  from    Categories
 where    Category = #URL.Category#
 </cfquery>



<cfif URL.Category NEQ "">
    <cfif Compare(URL.Category, "2") EQ 0>
        <span style="color: red;">The Category <cfoutput>#URL.Category#</cfoutput> already exist within the database.</span>
    <cfelse>
        <cfoutput><span style="color: Green;">#URL.Category# is available</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: In the name of all that is holy...stop using Access. Access is not really a viable option for the back end of a web application. You may experience performance issues under even small load. Use something like MySQL or PostgreSQL - both free, both much more powerful than Access.

Comment: What is the significance of the number 2 in your compare function?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, use cfqueryparam when passing dynamic values to your queries, especially so if it's something the users can specify.

Secondly, when using an aggregate function like Count() you need to then specify an alias if you want to use that value later on.

```
<cfquery name="TagCheck" datasource="PostBlog">
  select    Count(Category) AS CategoryCount
  from    Categories
  where    Category = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.Category#" CFSQLType="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
</cfquery>
```

Finally, in your logic you should just need to then do:

```
<cfif URL.Category NEQ "">
    <cfif TagCheck.CategoryCount GT 0>
        <span style="color: red;">The Category <cfoutput>#URL.Category#</cfoutput> already exist within the database.</span>
    <cfelse>
        <cfoutput><span style="color: Green;">#URL.Category# is available</cfoutput>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Use `HTMLEncodedFormat` when you output anything to the page for the very same reasons that made you use `<cfqueryparam>`.

Comment: @Tomalak there is no HTMLEncodedFormat - do you mean URLEncodedFormat or HTMLEditFormat or HTMLCodeFormat?

Comment: HTMLEditFormat, of course. ;) My point remains valid, though.

Comment: sql keywords are not the best choice for aliases.  They could cause problems.